# improving sequence dot operator for matrix rows and plot of Norm-imaginary

Tags: plotting, matrix

I have written a code to Dot a row (conjugate of that) of mm to the next one:

```
mm={{1,2,I},{I,I,3},{2,6,I},{1,6,4},{1,4,5}}

 fIdD = ConstantArray[0, {Dimensions[mm][[1]] - 1, 2}];
    Do[

     fIdD[[j]][[1]] = j; 
     fIdD[[j]][[2]] = Dot[mm[[j]]\[Conjugate], mm[[j + 1]]]

    , {j, 1, Dimensions[mm][[1]] - 1}];
```

Is there any possibility to use of mathematica syntax instead of this code for this aim(dot a conjugated row to the next one).

```
fIdD={{1, 0}, {2, -5 I}, {3, 38 - 4 I}, {4, 45}}
```

And if I am going to plot the `{{1,Norm[0]},{2,Norm[-5I]},{3,Norm[38-4I]},{4,Norm[45]}}` with the `ListPlot`. same as this: however it is wrong: `ListPlot[{#1, Norm[ #2]}, & fIdD]`?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would simply do

```
Dot[Conjugate[#1], #2] & @@@ Partition[mm, 2, 1]
```

and do away with the sequential numbers, as those are easy enough to generate when needed any way ([`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html)?)  `ListPlot` does not need these indices.

But instead of jumping straight to the solution, let's take your code and improve it step by step.

1. Instead of `arr[[i]][[j]]` you can write `arr[[i,j]]`.  This is simpler and more readable.
2. You are pre-initializing an array of *known dimensions* and then compute *each element*.  This is never necessary in Mathematica.  This is what `Table` is for.

   At this point we have

   ```
   Table[
    {j, Conjugate[mm[[j]]].mm[[j + 1]]},
    {j, 1, Dimensions[mm][[1]] - 1}
   ]
   ```

   Much simper than the original code.

   Additionally, `Dimensions[mm][[1]]` is simpler and clearer as `Length[mm]`.
3. When you use the iterator in `Table` to index an array, there are usually simpler ways.  Instead of `Table[ f[ arr[[i]] ], {i, 1, Length[arr]}]` we can always write `Table[f[elem], {elem, arr}]`.

   But here you need to iterate through consecutive pairs of elements, not each element.  [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) can make a list of pairs (or tuples) from a simple list. `Partition[{a,b,c,d}, 2]` would give `{{a,b}, {c,d}}` while `Partition[{a,b,c,d}, 2, 1]` will give `{{a,b}, {b,c}, {c,d}`.  This latter is what you need.

   This changes our code to

   ```
   Table[
    Conjugate[elem[[1]]].elem[[2]],
    {elem, Partition[mm, 2, 1]}
   ]
   ```

   Instead of `elem[[1]]` people often write `First[elem]`, which might be more readable, depending on context.  Since we have a list of pairs, in this particular case `elem[[2]]` would be `Last[elem]`.

   You might rightly argue that this change is not really a simplification, and it also loses the integer index form the result.  But it leads up to the next step.
4. When we have a list of the form `list = {{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ..., {xn,yn}}`, and we need to transform it to `{f[x1,y1], f[x2,y2], ..., f[xn,yn]}`, one pattern I like to use is

   ```
   f @@@ list
   ```

   This is short for `Apply[f, list, {1}]`, please look up [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).  If we already have a pre-defined function `f`, this makes for very simple and clear code.  If we don't, we can construct `f` on the fly as a [pure function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

   This gives us the final version:

   ```
   result = Dot[Conjugate[#1], #2] & @@@ Partition[mm, 2, 1]
   ```

   One reason why I like this style is that I find `#1` much more readable than `elem[[1]]`.  Too many brackets give me a headache :-)

To re-insert the integer indices, you can use

```
Transpose[{Range@Length[result], result}]
```

But in applications that need the index of each element, `MapIndexed` can be useful too.  `MapIndexed[{First[#2], #1} &, result]` is another way to get the result, though I'd integrate `MapIndexed` with the step that ultimately uses these indices.

`ListPlot` does not need these indices, it automatically assumes *x* coordinates to be 1, 2, ... if they're not given.  So plotting is as simple as

```
ListPlot[ Norm /@ result ]
```

`f /@ list` is short for `Map[f, list]`, please look up [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html).

---

As you can see, Mathematica has many ways to do the same thing, and it's up to you to choose one.  I hope you found this little introduction educational.

Answer (score 5):

Also

```
Most@MapThread[Dot, {Conjugate@mm , RotateLeft@mm}]
```

Or

```
Dot @@@ Transpose@{Conjugate@mm , RotateLeft@mm} // Most
```

Or something like shooting yourself in the foot :D

```
ListCorrelate[{Conjugate, Identity}, mm, 1, 0, #1[#2] &, Dot, 1] // Most
```