# When to use @@@ vs. /@

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

So much thanks to Szabolcs in [improving sequence..](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90038/improving-sequence-dot-operator-for-matrix-rows-and-plot-of-norm-imaginary) for complete explanation. I am so glad to read all explanation which fundamentally remove the problem. But in number 4 of its explanation pointed to `Apply in {1} level`: As we show with `@@@`. But I have a problem with this function. As Szabolcs pointed, this function acts as:

```
list = {{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ..., {xn,yn}}, 
 f@@@list= {f[x1,y1], f[x2,y2], ..., f[xn,yn]}
```

But for example we want to use `Last` for a list as:

```
m = {{1, 2, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, I, 3}, {2, 6, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 6, 4}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 4, 5}}


Last@m

{1, 4, 5}


Apply[Last, {m}]= Last@@{m}

{1, 4, 5}

Last /@ m
{I, 0, 3, I, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5}
```

But `Apply[Last, {m}, {1}]` or `Last@@@{m}` doesn't have any result. I predicted that I should have `Last@@@ {m}={Last{1, 2, I},Last{0,0,0},....}` which is the result of `Last/@ m`.

Also I can't understand what is the exact differnce between  `Last@m` and `Last@@{m}`. I have confused with these syntax.

Comment: `@@@` supplies a sequence to the function being applied, with `n` slots where `n` is the length of the sublists you're mapping over. `Last` takes a list as an argument, so you need `Last/@m`, for understanding, the way to make `@@@` work is to do `Last[List@##]&@@@m`, but that's just tearing the list apart and putting it back together.

Comment: Notice the difference in Szabolcs explanation of `@@@` and `f/@{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}`, which gives `{f[{x1,y1}],f[{x2,y2}]}`

Comment: Some possible duplicates: [78240](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78240/tutorial-for-map-apply-etc), [46238](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46238/scan-vs-map-vs-apply), [70201](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70201/choose-between-apply-and-map)

Comment: Actually many operations can be phrased either in terms of `Apply` or `Map`.  I should have mentioned in my answer that `Map` tends to be quite a bit faster than `Apply`.  I still use `Apply` a lot in the exact same way I described, but for the times when performance is important, you should know that `Apply` tends not to be as fast as `Map`.

Comment: To stir the pot a little, `MapThread[f,{a,b}]===f@@@Transpose[{a,b}]` when `a` and `b` are lists of equal length.  I mentally think of `MapThread` as `zipWith` from Haskell.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I know this has been answered already on this site, but I cannot seem to find it.

`Map` and `Apply` do subtly different things. For example,

```
Map[f, {a,b,c}]
(* {f[a], f[b], f[c]} *)
```

If you have a list that is more deeply nested, without using the third argument which is for level specification, you get

```
Map[f, {{a,b}, {c}}]
(* {f[{a,b}], f[{c}]} *)
```

or, if you do use it

```
Map[f, {{a, b}, {c}}, 2]
(* {f[{f[a], f[b]}], f[{f[c]}]} *)
Map[f, {{a, b}, {c}}, {1,2}]
(* {f[{f[a], f[b]}], f[{f[c]}]} *)
Map[f, {{a, b}, {c}}, {2}]
(* {{f[a], f[b]}, {f[c]}} *)
```

But, in every case, `Map` applies `f` to each element as is.

`Apply` does not do that; it explicitly replaces the `Head` of the element with `f`, as follows:

```
Apply[f, bob[a]] (* f @@ bob[a] *)
(* f[a] *)
Apply[f, {{a, b}, {c}}, {1}] (* f @@@ {{a, b}, {c}} *)
(* {f[a, b], f[c]} *)
Apply[f, {{a, b}, {c}}, {0, 1}]
(* f[f[a, b], f[c]] *)
```

On the surface, these look a lot like the results from `Map`, but the key difference is `Apply` does not work on something that is `AtomQ` as they are effectively headless (except in special cases), e.g.

```
Through[{AtomQ, ValueQ}[a]]
(* {True, False} *)
f @@ a
(* a *)
f @@@ {a}
(* {a} *)
```

For your application, you have nested lists, and to see how those are interpreted, use `FullForm`, e.g.

```
FullForm@{{1, 2, I}, {0, 0, 0}}
(* List[List[1, 2, Complex[0, 1]], List[0, 0, 0]] *)
```

(As an aside, note how `I` is interpreted as `Complex[0,1]`, but despite this, `AtomQ@Complex[0,1]` returns `True`.)

So, you want to use `Map`, e.g.

```
Last /@ {{1, 2, I}, {0, 0, 0}}
(* {I, 0} *)
```

because `@@@` will replace the heads of the inner lists with `Last`, e.g.

```
f @@@ {{1, 2, I}, {0, 0, 0}} (* where f is standing in for Last *)
(* {f[1, 2, I], f[0, 0, 0]} *)
```

Comment: Since this is aimed at mid-level new users, it might be useful to point out that when `Apply` is used on a list of lists, `List` itself is a head and that `{...}` is just shorthand. I think people often overlook until the first time they're really confronted with it, like this. +1

Comment: @N.J.Evans valid point. Expanded.

Comment: …and for the kids at home, `FullForm[]` will help you in playing "spot the difference". :)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I made a note on `I` being `AtomQ` despite its complex inner structure.

Comment: @rcollyer So `You` are `AtomQ`! I was looking for you! :D

Comment: @bel, nono, `Who` is `AtomQ`… :)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. no, he's on `First`.

Comment: @rcollyer, besides so thanks for your explanation. Imagine and understanding what you say is easy. your example using fullform helps me and my friend. `FullForm[f @@@ {{1, 2, I}, {0, 0, 0}}]=List[f[1, 2, Complex[0, 1]], f[0, 0, 0]]` and `f` can not work. But `Last @@@ {{{1, 2, I}}, {{0, 0, 0}}}={I, 0}`. We are so happy that we are able to understand. `FullForm[f @@@ {{{1, 2, I}}, {{0, 0, 0}}}]=List[f[List[[1, 2, Complex[0, 1]]],f[List[0,0,0]]]`

Comment: I wonder if this is similar enough to [(46238)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121) for me to mark it as a duplicate?  Obviously this answer is valuable to people and I don't wish to disparage it.  But I *think* I covered the same material before?

Comment: I joined two others in voting to close.  I am still interested if you disagree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that's one I was looking for.